# Error when get connection string: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0. Below is my code.

**Startup:**

```
namespace foo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
            services.AddDbContext<fooContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UserDatabase")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "UserDatabase": "Server=DESKTOP-FSES7UK;Database=xxx;User Id=sa; Password=xxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    }
  }
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: try having ConnectionString at the top in JSON file

Comment: It works, you are professional

Comment: Yes @Sajeetharan is right. You have your ConnectionStreings inside of Logging. There it will not be found. move _ConnectionStrings_ outside of _logging_ at top level

Comment: thank you, I catch the mistake type so many times. I will remember it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, try to move your connection string to the top (suggestion) fix is to take the key *`"ConnectionStrings"` *outside of **`logging`** key

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "UserDatabase": "Server=DESKTOP-FSES7UK;Database=xxx;User Id=sa; Password=xxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
```

Comment: `try to move your connection string to the top` -- This is not a problem! You can put it anywhere inside the `appsetings.json`.

Comment: That's not the actual problem, but my suggestion to have it at the top

Comment: `or outside of the logging key`-- That means this is also not mandatory!! This is mandatory.You can not put `OR` with the previous sentence!

Comment: haha! thanks for correcting it. I hope OP got the answer :) so never mind.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Welcome! but correct answer was posted before you modified your answer so many times 

Comment: my intention is not to get upvote, he managed to fix it after seeing my comment in the first place. so let him pick the correct answer. keep it cool :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your `ConnectionStrings` object has been a property of `Logging` object. Write your `appsettings.json` as follows:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "UserDatabase": "Server=DESKTOP-FSES7UK;Database=xxx;User Id=sa; Password=xxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```